# ¿Hay una forma de que al no presionar ningún botón, quede por defecto uno y se pueda enviar con jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Lo que pasa es que tengo por defecto un boton ya seleccionado el cual quiero que, si un usuario no le hunde a ninguno de los dos botones, entonces quede uno seleccionado por defecto y se pueda enviar por jquery. Les muestro cómo lo he estado haciendo.

Si hay alguna forma de hacer que quede por defecto uno de esos dos botones y se pueda enviar, o si tengo que cambiar toda la estructura, le agradecería

HTML

```js
$("body").on("click", ".botones", function() {

  
    const valorEnviar= $(this).data('value');


        $("body").on("click", "#botonSubmit", function(e) {
           

            $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'datos/enviar/',
                 dataType: 'text',
                 data: $('#formID').serialize() + '&caja='+ valorEnviar,
                success: function(response){
    
                 console.log(response);                    

                }
                 
            })

            e.preventDefault();
        })

    

})
//La busque si era posible esto, y no
.fail(function(){

    //Esto me lo inventé, es un ejemplo de lo que pasaría si no presiona el boton y entonces 
    $("body").on("click", "#botonSubmit", function(e) {
           

        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'datos/enviar/',
             dataType: 'text',
             data: $('#formID').serialize() + '&caja=9876',
            success: function(response){

             console.log(response);                    
   
            }
             
        })
        

        e.preventDefault();
    })

})
```

```html
<!---<form action='datos/enviar/' method='POST' id='formID'>--->
<button data-value='1234' type='button' class='botones'>CAJA 1</button>
<button data-value='9876' type='button' class='botones'>CAJA POR DEFECTO</button>
<button>Enviar post</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Si necesitas un valor por defecto, lo adecuado sería usar _input radio_, marcando uno como seleccionado. Si quieres aplicar estilos para simular botones, hay formas de hacerlo con un poco de CSS y, tal vez, algo de Javascript. También podrías hacer que cada botón procese el formulario, quitando el "Enviar post" y haciéndolo aún más sencillo.

Comment: De que modo el usuario haría un envío sin apretar el boton A o el B ?? Es decir, para que o cual es la función del botón C ?

Comment: el boton C es el submit